# filter negative timestamp oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi is there a way to filter out negative timestamps that arrise out of a timestamp diffference performed on two columns?

Comment: What keeps you from writing a `WHERE` clause? In other words: Please show why your current attempts haven't worked yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an appropriate `where` condition

```
where timestamp_one - timestamp_two < interval '0' second
```